# New tab opening when viewing parent comment on Youtube

Tags: tabs, youtube, comments

there's a problem with the new commenting system on YT: every time I click on the link to see what's what the parent comment to the one I am viewing, it opens in a new tab, with the video starting over again in the second tab. It is horrible and makes comment viewing a torture. Before the changes comments would show immediately above the answering comment in the same tab and it was easy to browse. 
Is there any option of turning off this new tab poppping? I'd actually like to get the whole system back but it is apparently unavailable...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should contact youtube support. I dont see how you can get help with this here...

Comment: Exactly! I've been redirected here from YT support page. Thos whole Google-messing-youtube thing goes worse and worse.